# Failed to compile JSP files during Glass QuickStart for Java

Tags: google-app-engine, google-mirror-api

`enter code here`I am attempting to use the Mirror API.  I am an explorer with Glass.  My Mirror API is turned on in the API console.

The instructions I am following are here:

https://developers.google.com/glass/quickstart/java

I get to step 2 of Deploying.  I am on a Windows machine and cd into app engine sdk bin folder and run the command specified but I modify the last parameter to be fully qualified.

It looks like this:

```
C:\Users\mscheel\Documents\Work\Glass\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.6\bin>appcfg.sh --o
auth2 update C:\Users\mscheel\Documents\Work\Glass\mirror-quickstart
-java-master\web
```

The very first time I ran this I got a web popup with an oauth dialog and got a success code that I pasted into the running app and then got an error, like this one I am pasting in from a subsequent run:

```
Welcome to Git (version 1.7.9-preview20120201)


Run 'git help git' to display the help index.
Run 'git help <command>' to display help for specific commands.
********************************************************
There is a new version of the SDK available.
-----------
Latest SDK:
Release: 1.8.0
Timestamp: Wed May 01 12:01:15 MDT 2013
API versions: [1.0]

-----------
Your SDK:
Release: 1.7.6
Timestamp: Fri Mar 15 19:18:56 MDT 2013
API versions: [1.0]

-----------
Please visit https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads for the latest SD
K.
********************************************************
Reading application configuration data...
May 27, 2013 11:29:15 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReade
r readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:/Users/mscheel/Documents/Work/Glass/mirror-quicks
tart-java-master/web\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
May 27, 2013 11:29:15 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlRea
der readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:/Users/mscheel/Documents/Work/Glass/mirror-quicks
tart-java-master/web\WEB-INF/web.xml
Beginning server interaction for bitcoinupdate...
0% Created staging directory at: 'C:\Users\mscheel\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg8499
594854129199289.tmp'
5% Using java7 runtime: false
8% Scanning for jsp files.
11% Compiling jsp files.

Error Details:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.createCompiler(JspCompilation
Context.java:238)
        at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.createCompiler(JspCompilation
Context.java:214)
        at org.apache.jasper.JspC.processFile(JspC.java:1181)
        at org.apache.jasper.JspC.execute(JspC.java:1341)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalJspC.main(LocalJspC.java:
40)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalJspC$LocalCompiler.<clini
t>(LocalJspC.java:53)
        ... 7 more
Error while executing: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe -classpath
/C:/Users/mscheel/Documents/Work/Glass/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.6/lib/impl/appengi
ne-api-labs.jar;/C:/Users/mscheel/Documents/Work/Glass/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.6/
lib/impl/appengine-api-stubs.jar;/C:/Users/mscheel/Documents/Work/Glass/appengin
e-java-sdk-1.7.6/lib/impl/appengine-api.jar;/C:/Users/mscheel/Documents/Work/Gla
ss/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.6/lib/impl/appengine-local-runtime.jar;/C:/Users/msche
el/Documents/Work/Glass/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.6/lib/impl/google_sql.jar;C:\User
s\mscheel\Documents\Work\Glass\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.6\lib\shared\appengine-loc
al-runtime-shared.jar;C:\Users\mscheel\Documents\Work\Glass\appengine-java-sdk-1
.7.6\lib\shared\el-api.jar;C:\Users\mscheel\Documents\Work\Glass\appengine-java-
sdk-1.7.6\lib\shared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-ant-1.7.1.jar;C:\Users\mscheel\Doc
uments\Work\Glass\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.6\lib\shared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-a
nt-launcher-1.7.1.jar;C:\Users\mscheel\Documents\Work\Glass\appengine-java-sdk-1
.7.6\lib\shared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-jasper-6.0.29.jar;C:\Users\mscheel\Docu
ments\Work\Glass\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.6\lib\shared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-ja
sper-el-6.0.29.jar;C:\Users\mscheel\Documents\Work\Glass\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.
6\lib\shared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-tomcat-juli-6.0.29.jar;C:\Users\mscheel\Do
cuments\Work\Glass\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.6\lib\shared\jsp-api.jar;C:\Users\msch
eel\Documents\Work\Glass\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.6\lib\shared\servlet-api.jar;C:\
Users\mscheel\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg8499594854129199289.tmp\WEB-INF\classes;C
:\Users\mscheel\AppData\Local\Temp\1369675757138-0;C:\Users\mscheel\AppData\Loca
l\Temp\appcfg8499594854129199289.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.6.jar
;C:\Users\mscheel\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg8499594854129199289.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\a
ppengine-api-labs-1.7.6.jar;C:\Users\mscheel\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg8499594854
129199289.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\commons-codec-1.7.jar;C:\Users\mscheel\AppData\Local\T
emp\appcfg8499594854129199289.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\commons-logging-1.1.2.jar;C:\Users
\mscheel\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg8499594854129199289.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\google-api
-client-1.14.1-beta.jar;C:\Users\mscheel\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg84995948541291
99289.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\google-api-client-appengine-1.14.1-beta.jar;C:\Users\msche
el\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg8499594854129199289.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\google-api-clien
t-servlet-1.14.1-beta.jar;C:\Users\mscheel\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg849959485412
9199289.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\google-api-services-mirror-v1-rev2-1.14.1-beta.jar;C:\Us
ers\mscheel\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg8499594854129199289.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\google-
http-client-1.14.1-beta.jar;C:\Users\mscheel\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg8499594854
129199289.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\google-http-client-appengine-1.14.1-beta.jar;C:\Users\
mscheel\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg8499594854129199289.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\google-http
-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.jar;C:\Users\mscheel\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg849959
4854129199289.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\google-oauth-client-1.14.1-beta.jar;C:\Users\msche
el\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg8499594854129199289.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\google-oauth-cli
ent-appengine-1.14.1-beta.jar;C:\Users\mscheel\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg84995948
54129199289.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\google-oauth-client-servlet-1.14.1-beta.jar;C:\Users
\mscheel\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg8499594854129199289.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\guava-14.0
.1.jar;C:\Users\mscheel\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg8499594854129199289.tmp\WEB-INF
\lib\httpclient-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\mscheel\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg849959485412
9199289.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\httpcore-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\mscheel\AppData\Local\Temp\a
ppcfg8499594854129199289.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar;C:\Users\ms
cheel\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg8499594854129199289.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\jackson-mappe
r-asl-1.9.11.jar;C:\Users\mscheel\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg8499594854129199289.t
mp\WEB-INF\lib\jdo2-api-2.3-eb.jar;C:\Users\mscheel\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg849
9594854129199289.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:\Users\mscheel\AppData\Local
\Temp\appcfg8499594854129199289.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-ant-1.7.1.j
ar;C:\Users\mscheel\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg8499594854129199289.tmp\WEB-INF\lib
\repackaged-appengine-ant-launcher-1.7.1.jar;C:\Users\mscheel\AppData\Local\Temp
\appcfg8499594854129199289.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jakarta-jstl-1.1
.2.jar;C:\Users\mscheel\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg8499594854129199289.tmp\WEB-INF
\lib\repackaged-appengine-jakarta-standard-1.1.2.jar;C:\Users\mscheel\AppData\Lo
cal\Temp\appcfg8499594854129199289.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jasper-6
.0.29.jar;C:\Users\mscheel\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg8499594854129199289.tmp\WEB-
INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jasper-el-6.0.29.jar;C:\Users\mscheel\AppData\Local
\Temp\appcfg8499594854129199289.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-jasper-jdt-
6.0.29.jar;C:\Users\mscheel\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg8499594854129199289.tmp\WEB
-INF\lib\repackaged-appengine-tomcat-juli-6.0.29.jar;C:\Users\mscheel\AppData\Lo
cal\Temp\appcfg8499594854129199289.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar;C:\Users\
mscheel\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg8499594854129199289.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\transaction
-api-1.1.jar;C:\Users\mscheel\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg8499594854129199289.tmp\W
EB-INF\lib\xpp3-1.1.4c.jar; -Dcom.google.apphosting.runtime.use_java7=false com.
google.appengine.tools.development.LocalJspC -uriroot C:\Users\mscheel\AppData\L
ocal\Temp\appcfg8499594854129199289.tmp -p org.apache.jsp -l -v -webinc C:\Users
\mscheel\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg8499594854129199289.tmp\WEB-INF\generated_web.
xml -d C:\Users\mscheel\AppData\Local\Temp\1369675757138-0 -javaEncoding UTF-8


com.google.appengine.tools.admin.JspCompilationException: Failed to compile jsp
files.
Unable to update app: Failed to compile jsp files.
Please see the logs [C:\Users\mscheel\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg49961834510221726
1.log] for further information.
```

I am using Eclipse and to get the project to build I had to a) use the 1.7.6 App Engine SDK, b) change my JRE from jre7 to jdk1.6.0_25 (otherwise I would get a JSP problem) c) wipe out old maven and start fresh with a new install and blow away old settings

Regarding b:

[image]

Any ideas mirror-api team?  Anybody else out there get this to work on Windows with Eclipse?

After a comment from Jenny Murphy am sharing the output of maven compile which succeeds with warnings:

```
C:\Users\mscheel\Documents\Work\Glass\mirror-quickstart-java-master>mvn compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for
com.google:glass-java-starter:jar:0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be
 unique: javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar -> duplicate declaration of version 2.5 @
 line 73, column 17
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten t
he stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support buildin
g such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building glass-java-starter 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:copy-dependencies (default) @ glass-java-
starter ---
[INFO] google-api-client-1.14.1-beta.jar already exists in destination.
[INFO] google-api-client-appengine-1.14.1-beta.jar already exists in destination
.
[INFO] google-api-client-servlet-1.14.1-beta.jar already exists in destination.
[INFO] google-api-services-mirror-v1-rev2-1.14.1-beta.jar already exists in dest
ination.
[INFO] appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.6.jar already exists in destination.
[INFO] appengine-api-labs-1.7.6.jar already exists in destination.
[INFO] jsr305-1.3.9.jar already exists in destination.
[INFO] guava-14.0.1.jar already exists in destination.
[INFO] google-http-client-1.14.1-beta.jar already exists in destination.
[INFO] google-http-client-appengine-1.14.1-beta.jar already exists in destinatio
n.
[INFO] google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.jar already exists in destination.

[INFO] google-oauth-client-1.14.1-beta.jar already exists in destination.
[INFO] google-oauth-client-appengine-1.14.1-beta.jar already exists in destinati
on.
[INFO] google-oauth-client-servlet-1.14.1-beta.jar already exists in destination
.
[INFO] commons-codec-1.7.jar already exists in destination.
[INFO] commons-logging-1.1.2.jar already exists in destination.
[INFO] jdo2-api-2.3-eb.jar already exists in destination.
[INFO] servlet-api-2.5.jar already exists in destination.
[INFO] transaction-api-1.1.jar already exists in destination.
[INFO] httpclient-4.0.1.jar already exists in destination.
[INFO] httpcore-4.0.1.jar already exists in destination.
[INFO] jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar already exists in destination.
[INFO] jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.11.jar already exists in destination.
[INFO] xpp3-1.1.4c.jar already exists in destination.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ glass-java
-starter ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources,
i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\mscheel\Documents\Work\Glass
\mirror-quickstart-java-master\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ glass-java-star
ter ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.817s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed May 29 20:54:23 MDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/243M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I tried this with JDK 1.7.0_21 as well.  I get the same error, the only difference is in this line: 5% Using java7 runtime: false ... it now says true.

Comment: Still looking for help on this.

Comment: Are you able to deploy other App Engine apps?  Does the mvn compile step succeed?

Comment: It succeeds with warnings.  Too much to paste in a comment.  I'll update the original post, look above.

Comment: Thanks! The Maven part looks like it's working. Can you deploy other App Engine apps?

Comment: It looks like so.  If I create a new Web Application Project in Eclipse (I uncheck the GWT SDK box) and just click the debug button it deploys to http://localhost:8888/ which shows "Hello App Engine!"  Does that count as a yes?

Comment: Can you use the appcfg.sh tool to deploy it like you're trying to do for the quick start?

Comment: Can we focus on the "failed to compile Jsp files" error?  To answer your question, I don't know, if I try to do that I get an error because the test project does not have a web folder that is expected.  So it seems like a bad test.  I opened up appcfg.sh and noticed it references SDK_BIN which is not set on my system, is that a problem?  Thanks for your help.  Let me know what other info I can share.

Comment: An update - I got this to work on Mac OS X with much less effort.  I followed the instructions more or less (there is a typo I think, it says to cd into "mirror-java-starter" but it should say "mirror-quickstart-java-master").  I still want this to work on my dev pc and would appreciate more help.  If it makes sense you can contact me directly at my first name + "wearsglass" + g mail

Comment: I'm not sure what to say at this point. You're seeing an error when running appcfg. The next step is to determine if there's an issue with the project or the App Engine SDK config. The easiest way to do this, is to attempt to deploy a different App Engine app, as I've just asked twice. Beyond this, I have no additional advice.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30946/discussion-between-mark-scheel-and-jenny-murphy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this to work on my Windows 7 box:

```
    C:\Users\mscheel\Documents\Work\Glass\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.6\bin>appcfg.sh --o
auth2 update C:\Users\mscheel\Documents\Work\Glass\mirror-quickstart-java-master
\web
Welcome to Git (version 1.7.9-preview20120201)


Run 'git help git' to display the help index.
Run 'git help <command>' to display help for specific commands.
Reading application configuration data...
Jun 01, 2013 12:04:33 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReade
r readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:/Users/mscheel/Documents/Work/Glass/mirror-quicks
tart-java-master/web\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Jun 01, 2013 12:04:33 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlRea
der readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:/Users/mscheel/Documents/Work/Glass/mirror-quicks
tart-java-master/web\WEB-INF/web.xml
Beginning server interaction for bitcoinupdate...
0% Created staging directory at: 'C:\Users\mscheel\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg3034
149135282611799.tmp'
5% Using java7 runtime: true
8% Scanning for jsp files.
11% Compiling jsp files.
warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'com.goo
gle.appengine.tools.compilation.DatastoreCallbacksProcessor' less than -source '
1.7'
1 warning
Jun 01, 2013 12:04:36 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlRea
der readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\mscheel\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg303414913
5282611799.tmp\WEB-INF/web.xml
20% Scanning files on local disk.
25% Initiating update.
28% Cloning 14 static files.
31% Cloning 73 application files.
40% Uploading 3 files.
52% Uploaded 1 files.
61% Uploaded 2 files.
68% Uploaded 3 files.
73% Initializing precompilation...
77% Sending batch containing 2 file(s) totaling 2KB.
80% Sending batch containing 1 blob(s) totaling 0KB.
90% Deploying new version.
95% Closing update: new version is ready to start serving.
98% Uploading index definitions.

Update completed successfully.
Success.
Cleaning up temporary files...
```

This took a lot of effort, unfortunately, but the final solution was fairly simple.  But first the problem.  If you look in my original post at the execution you can see this line:

```
Error while executing: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe -classpath
```

In the top code snippet.

That JRE is bad. I want to be using a JDK.  I discovered this eventually by running through Eclipse (trying to deploy to app engine) and saw a better error message there.

The solution for Eclipse was to modify my Eclipse.ini as instructed here:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

This forces eclipse to use the JDK instead of the JRE to allow deploy to app engine through eclipse (gets you past the jsp compilation failure).

My exact ini file snippet is:

```
...
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\javaw.exe
...
```

But this did not fix things through the command line via appcfg.  This page had the solution:

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1226

Which appears to be windows specific, and will be a problem for anyone that previously installed JRE 6 at least.  You have to uninstall all old JRE's.  See comment #6 on that page.  I did this through the uninstall applications GUI in Windows.

Once I did both these things I no longer have a failure compiling JSP's related to the mirror api.